# Possible to have a video wall through a device cluster?

Tags: wireless-networking, video, vlc-media-player

I was asked if I could basically make a video wall with Android tablets. I know you can make a video wall with VLC, but can I set up a video wall that will split the video into 4 X 4 screens (tablets) through Wi-Fi? Typically when I see clustered machines for a video, it is used through a physical controller. Can you set up VLC to establish a video wall and send each piece to the tablets?

Answer (score 0):

You want a Junkyard Jumbotron!....

http://civic.mit.edu/blog/csik/junkyard-jumbotron

Unfortunately I think the software can only do still images now and now video - but video is certainly possible with this technique.

You can hack a solution by simultaneously opening a VLC connection from each tablet onto the host display and then carefully zoom each tablet's window so it only shows the quarter of the main display that it should be showing. Each tablet would be receiving the full screen, but only showing it's quarter of it.

Answer (score 0):

[This doesn't answer the "How" part of your question, but I had some thoughts for you on the "is it physically doable?" implicit question.]

Does it matter what resolution the source material is? For example, with some tablets reaching greater-than-full-HD native resolutions of 2560x1600, you could end up needing 10240 x 6400 (16.4 megapixels) video to use their full resolution. You probably don't have a camera that can take 16.4 megapixel video, so you probably don't need to support the full aggregate resolution of your tablet video wall. And that's good, because even with H.264 compression you'd probably want an 8mbps stream for each tablet to make it look good, and unless all your tablets have at least 2x2 802.11n (a.k.a. "N300"), you probably don't have enough Wi-Fi bandwidth to deliver all that video to all those tablets at once.

So let's say the best video source you can get is 1920x1080p30, which looks okay with H.264 compression at, say, 6mbps. Now you just need to stream 480x270 video to each tablet, and you fullscreen that video window and let the tablet's built-in scalers scale that up to full resolution. Each 480x270 stream is likely well under half a megabit per second to each tablet, which is well within the the capability of any flavor of 802.11n (assuming you have a dedicated AP located nearby to the video wall, and you have a clean channel to use, etc.).

So I'd say bandwidth wise, chopping up 1080p30 video and streaming it via Wi-Fi to the tablet video wall is totally doable.

Whatever you do for the streaming protocol, you probably want to do separate unicast streams rather than trying to run one multicast stream that each tablet breaks up for itself. That's because multicast is much more expensive on Wi-Fi than unicast is; multicast packets have to be sent at lower data rates than unicasts, so they take up much more airtime.

If you want to use @bigjosh's suggestion of sending the same stream to all devices, and zooming them each to a different part of the whole, beware that a 6 mbit stream sent 16 times is 96mbps, which may be more bandwidth that an typical tablet's 1x1 N Wi-Fi (N150, which really only gets perhaps 90 mbps of TCP/IP throughput max) can handle. Even though each tablet only needs 6mbps, it all has to come across the same channel unless you set up a dual-band AP, or multiple APs, and distribute your tablets evenly across the APs.

You could *try* doing that 6mbps stream as a Wi-Fi multicast, but for that, you'd want to make sure you have a Wi-Fi AP that lets you adjust the multicast rate, and you'd want to set the multicast rate above 6mbps (probably above 12 mbps). And again, use a dedicated AP for this video wall, have it near the video wall, and put it on a clean channel.